# Opencv image to array issue

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv

Im having an issue using opencv trying to convert an image to an array. The conversion works however i seem to have incorrect dimensions in the resulting array:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    auto img = cv::imread("test.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    std::cout << "img cols: " << img.cols << " img rows: "
        << img.rows << " channels: " << img.channels() << std::endl;

    std::vector<float> array2;
    if (img.isContinuous()) {
        array2.assign((float*)img.ptr(0), (float*)(img.ptr(img.rows - 1)) + img.cols);
        std::cout << array2.size() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output from the first print line results in :

img cols: 416 img rows: 416 channels: 3

Which is correct, however after assigning the data to the array the dimensions are : 518336 , when they should be 519168 (416*416*3).

Could anyone possibly suggest what exactly is causing the resulting array to be smaller than expected?

Comment: In this snippet, `img` will be `CV_8UC3`, so accessing the elements as floats is incorrect. (Also there are template overloads of `cv::Mat::ptr` that would let you avoid those c-style casts) Your calculation of the "end" pointer seems to ignore the fact that there are multiple channels. (That's why you're short by 2*416 elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- First of all, `cv::imread("test.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);` will (on success) return a `cv::Mat` with datatype `CV_8UC3`, however you're accessing the elements as `float`s. This means that the values you will read will be garbage, and you will also end up reading past the end of the pixel buffer.

  If you want floats, then you need to do some conversion/casting, either before or during the act of copying.
- The second problem lies in your calculation of the "end" pointer, where you seem to forget that you're dealing with a multi-channel `cv::Mat`. In case of a `CV_8UC3` matrix, each pixel is represented by 3 bytes, hence there are `cols*channels` bytes per row. (That's why you're short by 2*416 elements)
- Not really a problem, but a limitation -- your code only works for continuous `Mat`s.

---

I would take a somewhat different approach, and take advantage of functionality provided by OpenCV.

### Option 1

Use [`cv::Mat::copyTo`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a33fd5d125b4c302b0c9aa86980791a77), since [`OutputArray`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/d9e/classcv_1_1__OutputArray.html) can wrap a `std::vector<T>`. However, for this to work, the source `Mat` needs to have 1 channel and 1 row. We can achieve this efficiently using [`cv::Mat::reshape`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4eb96e3251417fa88b78e2abd6cfd7d8), but the `Mat` needs to be continuous, so that limitation stays.

```
std::vector<uchar> to_array_v1(cv::Mat3b const& img)
{
    std::vector<uchar> a;
    if (img.isContinuous()) {
        img.reshape(1, 1).copyTo(a);
    }
    return a;
}
```

### Option 2

Use [`MatIterator`s](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/dfe/classcv_1_1MatIterator__.html) which we can get using [`cv::Mat::begin`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a33ee3bc402827f587a5ad64b568d6986) and [`cv::Mat::end`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a9dd628eeccedea6e181ca54d41830a62). The iterators will work correctly even on a non-continuous `Mat`, however we need them to iterate over bytes, so we need to `reshape` the matrix to a single channel one. Since we're not changing the number of rows, the reshape will also work on a non-continuous `Mat`.

```
std::vector<uchar> to_array_v2(cv::Mat3b const& img)
{
    cv::Mat1b tmp(img.reshape(1));
    return std::vector<uchar>(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
}
```

### Option 3

The approach suggested by [Silencer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3547485/silencer), using the rather poorly documented [`cv::Mat::datastart`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aeda6d607bfc629a95f59e7b538832172) and [`cv::Mat::dataend`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ae756e84c94cbcf4c152ed0e67edb71ca) members. The documentation of [`cv::Mat::locateROI`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a40b5b3371a9c2a4b2b8ce0c8068d7c96) sheds some more light on the meaning of those member variables:

> However, each submatrix contains information (represented by `datastart` and `dataend` fields) that helps reconstruct the original matrix size and the position of the extracted submatrix within the original matrix.

This means that this approach has 2 limitations: it needs a continous matrix, and it won't work correctly for a submatrix, even if it's continuous. (Specifically, for a continuous submatrix, it would return the entire buffer of the "parent" matrix)

```
std::vector<uchar> to_array_v3(cv::Mat3b const& img)
{
    std::vector<uchar> a;
    if (img.isContinuous() && !img.isSubmatrix()) {
        a.assign(img.datastart, img.dataend);
    }
    return a;
}
```

---

### Test Code

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>


// Paste implementations from the answer here


cv::Mat3b test_image()
{
    cv::Mat1b m(4, 4);
    std::iota(m.begin(), m.end(), 0);

    cv::Mat3b img;
    cv::merge(std::vector<cv::Mat1b>{ m * 3, m * 3 + 1, m * 3 + 2 }, img);
    return img;
}

void print(cv::Mat3b const& img)
{
    std::cout << "Continuous: " << (img.isContinuous() ? "yes" : "no") << '\n';
    std::cout << "Submatrix: " << (img.isSubmatrix() ? "yes" : "no") << '\n';
    std::cout << img << "\n";
}

void print(std::vector<uchar> const& a)
{
    if (a.empty()) {
        std::cout << "empty";
    } else {
        for (auto n : a) {
            std::cout << int(n) << ' ';
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void test(cv::Mat3b const& img)
{
    print(img);
    print(to_array_v1(img));
    print(to_array_v2(img));
    print(to_array_v3(img));
}

int main()
{
    cv::Mat3b img(test_image());
    test(img);

    cv::Mat3b img2(img(cv::Rect(0, 0, 3, 3)));
    test(img2);

    cv::Mat3b img3(img(cv::Rect(1, 1, 3, 1)));
    test(img3);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Running this program will produce the following output:

```
Continuous: yes
Submatrix: no
[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11;
  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23;
  24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35;
  36,  37,  38,  39,  40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47]
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 
Continuous: no
Submatrix: yes
[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8;
  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20;
  24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32]
empty
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 
empty
Continuous: yes
Submatrix: yes
[ 15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23]
15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
empty
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mat img = imread("test.png");
std::vector<uchar> arr;

// convert Mat of CV_8UC3 to std::vector<uchar> if continuous
if(img.isContinuous()){
    arr.assign(img.datastart, img.dataend);
}
```

Comment: Note that this approach will return an incorrect result if `img` is a continuous submatrix (e.g. a single row). Of course, `imread` isn't very likely to return something like that, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: @DanMašek you can write your answer.